# Dúvida em trabalhar com múltiplos

Tags: arduino

Estou desenvolvendo um *Sketch* e eu preciso usar múltiplos de um, mas acho que não estou sabendo trabalhar direito com eles. Eu tenho um laço `FOR` que vai de 1 a 72 e eu preciso contar e ir mostrando as mensagens na tela. O problema é que tem mensagem que esta se repetindo devido mais de 1 número ser múltiplo de 3, como eu posso arrumar isso ?

**OBS:** Pelo laço ir até 72 é normal após exibir a ultima mensagem, começar tudo de novo, então terei 2 blocos de mensagens separadas.

Eu preciso fazer isso:

```
1 ) A cada 1  byte  exibe no terminal ( BLOCO ! )
2 ) A cada 21 bytes exibe no terminal ( BLOCO 2 )
3 ) A cada 29 bytes exibe no terminal ( BLOCO 3 )
4 ) A cada 35 bytes exibe no terminal ( BLOCO 4 )
5 ) A cada 36 bytes exibe no terminal ( BLOCO 5 )
```

**CÓDIGO:**

```
  for(i = 1; i < 72; i ++)
  {

    if ((i % 1 == 0) && ((i) % 1 == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("BLOCO 1");
    }
    else if ((i % 21 == 0) && ((i) % 3 == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("BLOCO 2");
    }
    else if ((i % 29 == 0) && ((i) % 3 == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("BLOCO 3");
    }
    else if ((i % 35 == 0) && ((i) % 5 == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("BLOCO 4");
    }
    else if ((i % 36 == 0) && ((i) % 3 == 0))
    {
      Serial.println("BLOCO 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflowPT! Poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta? Posso tentar lhe ajudar, mas ainda não compreendi o que você quer.

Comment: Olá Avelino. Obrigado pelas Boas Vindas. Nos if's fossem os multiplos e quando for TRUE exibe a mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua pergunta, precisas mostrar mensagens em conjunto de blocos de bytes. Portanto, da seguinte forma, serão impressas exatas 71 mensagens:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 72; i++) {

        if (i % 21 == 0) {
            Serial.println("BLOCO 2");
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 29 == 0) {
            Serial.println("BLOCO 3");
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 35 == 0) {
            Serial.println("BLOCO 4");
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 36 == 0) {
            Serial.println("BLOCO 5");
            continue;
        }

        Serial.println("BLOCO 1");
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado Avelino.

Comment: @abduzeedo funcionou?

Comment: Estou testando... Já posto o resultado.

Comment: Funcionou..........